# How to check if file's data is already in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently running into a problem where if I run this php more then once my image data that is currently in the database will duplicate. For example I uploaded 5 images to my upload file then clicked the script and everything was fine. When I added another image and clicked the script again I went from having 6 images in my database to 11. I was wondering how I could modify my code so that I can fix this problem.

```
include('mysql.php');

if ($handle = opendir('images')) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if($file!='.' && $file!='..') {
            $images[] = "('".$file."')";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

/* insert new record into the table images with the filename */
$query = "INSERT INTO images (filename) VALUES ".implode(',', $images)." ";
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    print mysql_error();
}
else {
    print "finished installing your images!";
}
```

Comment: You could make `filename` `UNIQUE`, so that only new, distinct, filenames are added.

Comment: you are imploding several images in one string to insert it in one row so, what you need exactly?
is it to create 1 row for each image in the database and prevent duplicates?

Answer (score 4):

You could make the 'filename' column a unique key and use `INSERT IGNORE`.

More about Insert ignore: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html